# Autolaunch flow not launching from process builder

Tags: lightning, visual-workflow, time-dependent-workflow

There is a process builder which is calling an auto-launch flow after 2 min. It's a time-based action
[image]

I am calling a basic auto launch flow which is just posting a chatter on the record created.

When testing the process builder, I can see the record in Time-Based Workflow, which ensures that the process builder is running fine, but the action I made in flow is not executing.
[image]

I am passing below variable when launching flow
[image]

Post To chatter Action configuration Image
[image]

Any Idea what could be the issue.
This is what we were calling from the process builder.

[image]

And based on the below condition it executes the logic. It is working for all conditions except open house source. Is the issue due to any flow limits?
[image]

Comment: Do you get any error messages in your email when debugging this?

Comment: When debugging, it's working fine.  The fault path is also not executing.

Comment: do you have the proper chatter component on the Lead record page (for the relevant Lead recordtype)?

Comment: Yes, it does show for process builder action but not for auto-launch flow

Comment: That is not what I asked: I asked if you get error messages in your email. If not, you might also consider building this with a flow instead of a process too.

Comment: My requirement is different. I want to send an autoresponder message whenever a lead is created in Salesforce. Their messages are based on the sources (Source field) on the lead record. This process was working fine until we added one more source condition. It just doesn't work for that one condition and works for everything else. I will edit the question with more photos to be clear.